# XmlHttpRequest status=0

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I have this ajax call from a javascript file and I want to pass as a parameter the id of the user that I want to delete:

```
function eliminaUtente(id,nome){
if (confirm("Sei sicuro di voler eliminare l'utente "
    + nome
    + "?")) {
var xmlHttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp2.open("POST", "EliminaUtente", true);
xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var params2 = "id=" + id;
xmlHttp2.send(params2);
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp2.readyState == 4) 
    {
                    alert(xmlHttp2.status);  <-----------this prints always 0!
        if (xmlHttp2.status == 200) //
        {
            alert("utente eliminato!");
        } else {
            alert("An error occurred while communicating with server.");
        }
    }
};
```

}
}

in the correspondant Servlet called EliminaUtente i have this code:

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    System.out.println(id);
    String query = "delete from utente where idutente=" + id;
    System.out.println(query);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Spinning?user=root");
        PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query);
        prest.executeUpdate();

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter ajaxWriter = response.getWriter();
        ajaxWriter.print("ok");
        ajaxWriter.flush();
        ajaxWriter.close();

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter ajaxWriter = response.getWriter();
        ajaxWriter.print("ko");
        ajaxWriter.flush();
        ajaxWriter.close();
    }

}
```

}

I can't understand where is the problem...can you help me please? ;)

Comment: Code 0 means that there was a connection problem.

Comment: yes but I can't understand where! the code seems right...

Comment: Read about prepared statement. You really don't want someone posting a request with `id=5 or 1=1` and have all your users deleted.

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean?

Comment: That anyone could send a request to your webapp with `id=5 or 1=1` as query string, and since you blindly concatenates the id to your SQL query, the following query would be executed: `delete from utente where idutente=5 or 1=1`, which would delete all the users in your application. That's why prepared statement should always be used instead of string concatenation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. What I described is a SQL injection attack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: It is not a solution to your problem, but better put the `xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function() { ...}` before the `xmlHttp2.send(params2);` (or even before the `open`). Otherwise the request might be processed before the assigned event handler gets the state change properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code and change a little bit i want to explain what did i and what i learn from it.I read some source. First i read [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object and [onreadyState](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) event.
I implement your example both `PUT` and `GET` action method.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.testServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

testServlet.java

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*super.doPost(req, resp);*/
        String strId = req.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(strId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.doGet(req, resp);
        String strId = req.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(strId);
    }
}
```

and main part NewFile.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="eliminaUtente('1')" width="100%" />
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function eliminaUtente(id) {

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "test/NewFile.jsp?id=" + id;
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(url);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                alert("utente eliminato!");
            } else {
                alert("An error occurred while communicating with server.");
            }
        };
    }
</script>
</html>
```

with this way i write the parameter 1(i hardcode it in jsp file method invoke) and write it to console, the first thing in here the difference your code and mine i remove the `xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` because if the method type is `POST` default encryption is this.

```
enctype = content-type [CI]
This attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of method is "post"). The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the INPUT element, type="file".
```

- So no need to enctype default is OK for `POST`.
- And this is open method signature `open(method, url, async, user, password)` here async is the parameter which means if it is false don't wait a response from server implement the other line when response is come it will run. If it is true wait until response is come. Actually i try bot of them and it is worked.
- Lastly i try it with `GET`. If you want use it with `GET` you should add `xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` code for encryption and remove the `url` parameter from `send()` method.

  function eliminaUtente(id) {

  ```
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "test/NewFile.jsp?id=" + id;
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
          xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlHttp.send();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
              alert("utente eliminato!");
          } else {
              alert("An error occurred while communicating with server.");
          }
      };
  }
  ```

Note: I try this code in firefox, i create xmlHttpRequest object. For all browser(include IE6) sure you know use:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

typo?

`alert(xmlHttp2.status);`  <-----------this prints always 0! Now has "2'

Comment: yes, sorry...I was wrong when I wrote the question...it prints 0 however!

Comment: But I am thinking that you need not be concerned with that... xmlHttp2.readyState goes from 0->4 (Uninitialized, Open, Sent, Receiving, Loaded) - so at xmlHttp2.readyState==4, you should be good to go. (Don't worry about .status)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I have to put false in this line:

```
xmlHttp2.open("POST", "EliminaUtente", FALSE);
```

Comment: Horrible idea.  You should really never use synchronous ajax requests,  as they will block the UI thread until the request completes.  If your app requires this, you need to take a closer look at your design and make some changes.